# No buttons on control bar - mediaelement.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

I have uploaded all of the MediaElement files, in the original directories, but in the Demos the videos and audio play fine but the Play, Volume and Full screen buttons are not visible on the control bar.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Has anyone else had this problem? The Play, Volume and Full screen buttons are still functional but there are no icons visible. It's the same on the Demos and a standalone install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also ran into the same problem. Make sure you have added the correct MIME types for SVG images on your server. If they are not there, or if they are mis-configured, your browser will not display them.

I handled this through .htaccess:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

If you still can't get the SVG images to appear, you can always change the background images in the CSS to use the .png versions of the control bar and play icons.

Comment: Thank you **spncr** for taking the time to Answer. It's very much appreciated. It was down to the MIME type not being added for SVG images. I've changed these to the PNG verion in CSS.

Answer (score 6):

After reading the first answer from spncr, I found no-svg classes in the MEjs stylesheet that used the PNG files instead of SVG. I wrapped my audio element with a DIV using that class.

```
<div class="no-svg">
  <audio id="player1" controls>
    <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mp3" >
    <p>This browser doesn't support audio.</p>
  </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Great find!  Adding mime types didn't work for me... this was a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, basically it was because i'd moved the files around and the CSS was looking in the wrong place for the controls image file.

In mediaelementplayer.css

```
 .mejs-controls .mejs-button button {
background: transparent url(controls.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Make sure the url of the background matches the actual location of the controls.png file.

Comment: Thanks **David** for taking the time to reply. It's very much appreciated. It was because the MIME type hadn't been added to server for SVG images so I've changed them to the PNG version in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the web.config file used instead of the .htaccess file on a Windows server.

```xml
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```